# toggle slide animation on top of web

Tags: css, css-animations, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a menu that slides on top of the rest of the web using bootstrap 4 (final) toogle options but the problem is it keeps ignoring the animation.

This is my html:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-mobile-div" aria-expanded="true">  
   Menu 
</button>
<br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida volutpat odio id congue. Cras vitae faucibus nisl. Mauris neque lacus, tincidunt a orci sit amet, cursus malesuada lacus. Sed ornare metus et sem 

<div id="menu-mobile-div" class="width collapse" aria-expanded="true">
  <div class="menu-mobile">
     ITEM1<br>
     ITEM2<br>
     ITEM3<br>
     ITEM4<br>
    <button class="pull-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-mobile-div" aria-expanded="true">  
      Menu       
    </button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.menu-mobile {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 256px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.collapsing.width {
    -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
    transition-property: width, visibility;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xjhj1x23/3/

I noticed the problem is the "position: fixed" of the div but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you copy the `.collapsing.width` from somewhere else?

Comment: you want to animate the menu from top to bottom or what...? what about the menu button when menu open..?

Comment: @Bhuwan I want it slide from de left to the right, and the menu button clones inside the menu as you can see in the example